# Tool to track the testing pyramid state

Tags: test-management, test-design, uiautomation, test-pyramid

Is there any tool for tracking testing pyramid state which visualises each stage of pyramid and where I can track disproportions of that?

p.s. I did a quick search and as I can see there are a plenty of tools for code coverage (this is mostly for unit tests) but nothing for tracking a whole pyramid.

Comment: The Test Pyramid is a heuristic - its goal is to be a general approach, not an objective/quantifiable metric. Such a tool would be misleading. A heuristic aims to guide, not to evaluate objectively.

Comment: Test Pyramid tells us about proportions of tests on each layer and proportions can be metric and you can display it and track it.

Comment: Mike Cohn does not talk about number of checks anywhere in Succeeding with Agile - he talks about risk assessment, which by nature demands an heuristical approach. Better check your sources rather than rely on second-hand interpretations.

Comment: Sorry, but that sounds very superficially. Tool I speak for is not the only thing you'll rely on - but in complex it could help to detect smth going wrong.

Comment: I just pointed out that such a tool would have only a weak relation to Cohn's Test Pyramid since this heuristic does not talk about what the tool does (counting number of checks). And "tracking testing pyramid state" implies a strong relation.

Comment: Ok, how would you know if your testing is pyramid or ice-cream or something else? You should be checking your source code, gather tests and put them on their layers. Is there another way to know how far / close your automation style to pyramid approach?

Answer (score 3):

I like the guidance from https://automationpanda.com/tag/testing-pyramid/: each layer of tests should be an order of magnitude smaller than below.

> The Testing Pyramid should be a guideline, not a hard rule. **Don’t
>   require hard proportions for test counts at each layer.** Why not?
>   Arbitrary metrics cause bad practices: a team might skip valuable
>   end-to-end tests or write needless unit tests just to hit numbers. W.
>   Edwards Deming would shudder!
>
> Instead, **use loose proportions to foster better retrospectives**.
>   Are we covering too many input combos through the Web UI when they
>   could be checked via service tests? Are there unit test coverage gaps?
>   Do we have a pyramid, a diamond, a funnel, a cupcake, or some other
>   wonky shape? Each layer’s test count should be roughly an order of
>   magnitude smaller than the layer beneath it. Large Web apps often have
>   10K unit tests, 1K service tests, and a few hundred Web UI tests.

The problem generally is that Unit tests, Integration tests and UI tests are written in separate efforts.  With different frameworks, languages, reporting, etc.

I think your two options are:

- Use an complete testing solution vendor and get feeds from all the different testing areas to construct a visualization of your pyramid.
- Manually have each layer communicated test totals to another small application that aggregates them for display.

Comment: I've suggested a format improvement, but really only the last section (starting *"The problem generally..."*) actually addresses what the OP asked.

Comment: Guidance is still guidance, that tool is in need of a team and team's product owner to track the state of pyramid - that helps to follow guidance.


The difference of code-stacks on each layer of pyramid is not a real problem, you just need to have access to source code and know masks of each layer tests, then you can summarize them and bring a pyramid-diagram to life.
Yes, to do that by my own is the option, but I'd like to know if there's any tool before I'l start implementing my own.

Comment: ^ a classic 'easy if you already know it' otherwise very hard.  The underlying problem there is that we are not all-knowing

Comment: @MichaelDurrant I'm not sure I've got that you said